# Equal Spacing in Title Headings - Parskip

Tags: titlesec, parskip

I have formatted the titles of chapters, sections etc but I can't get the spacing between their elements equal to each other because as I have seen the command `\setlength{\parskip}{10pt}` adds to those spaces. Why parskip plays a role in the spacing of the titles? How can I prevent that?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]%
{%
    \Huge \centering \bfseries%
}%
{%
    Chapter\\
    \vspace{10pt}
    \thechapter%
}%
{10pt}{}%
[%
    \vspace{20pt}\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}%
]

\setlength{\parskip}{10pt}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Title}

Text here

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the scope of `\centering`, `\\` issues `\par`, so the `\parskip` enters in the way. Just say `\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}\centering\bfseries`. Since the chapter titles are typeset inside a group, the value of `\parskip` will be restored for normal text.

<sub>Or, better, don't change the standard value of `\parskip`.</sub>